# BibLaTeX custom citation string with custom hyperlink

Tags: biblatex

I want a custom citation style in which the citation looks like a short name of the journal and year, and is hyperlinked to the DOI or journal web site, rather than to the reference list (bibliography).

One way to get close is by using `style=alphabetic` and specifying the `shorthand` value to be the citation format I want.

Below is a MWE that does not do what I want yet:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxnames=999,minalphanames=3,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{tabmet,
  author    = {Ulrich Fischer and Max Heinzler and Roland Kilgus and Friedrich Näher and Stefan Oesterle and Heinz Paetzold and Werner Röhrer and Andreas Stephan and Ralf Winkow},
  title     = {Tabellenbuch Metall},
  edition   = {42},
  year      = {2002},
  publisher = {Verlag Europa-Lehrmittel},
  location  = {Haan-Gruiten},
  shorthand={Verlag 2002}
}
@article{fakeart,
  author    = {Walter Schnell and Dietmar Gross and Werner Hauger},
  title = {Technische Mechanik},
  volume    = {2},
  title     = {Elastostatik},
  edition   = {4},
  publisher = {Springer},
  date      = {2002},
  location  = {Berlin},
  journal={Journal of BibTeX examples},
  shorthand={J Bib Examp 2002}
}
\end{filecontents*}
%shorthand={\href{http://doi.org/10.1257/jep.23.1.221}{J Bib Examp 2002}}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field[strwidth=4,strside=left,ifnames=1]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=left,ifnames=2]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
  }
}
%            \field{usera}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Citing these   \cite{tabmet,fakeart}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This produces a custom (actually, individually-specified in the database, so not ideal) citation format, but it does not let me link outside.

That is, I would like to write

```
  shorthand={\href{http://doi.org/10.1257/jep.23.1.221}{J Bib Examp 2002}}
```

in place of

```
  shorthand={J Bib Examp 2002}
```

But doing that gives errors.
What I am really after is to do this without using `shorthand`.
Can I define a style that uses the `url` field in the database and the, say, `journal` field in the database to make citations behave like

```
(\href{url}{journal year})
```

Comment: To whomever downvoted: leave a comment to make it better.   (And apply to rest of life)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question is  missing a complete example and you shouldn't link to external sources but describe what you want in the question.

Comment: Thanks. I have reframed the whole thing with a MWE that doesn't do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is best to separate the `shorthand` and its link into different fields. Then you don't have to mess with `\href` and avoid having to pass through unnecessary formatting commands.

If we don't want to reuse existing fields like `url`, `doi` etc., we need to define a new field that holds the link for the citation label. In the example below I called it `shorthandlink`. New fields need to be declared to `biblatex` in `.dbx` files (in the MWE below the `.dbx` file is generated with `filecontents`, in a real-world application one would just generate the file once and put it somewhere LaTeX can find it).

With `shorthandfield` available things are as easy as changing the field format responsible for linking citations to the bibliography.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{shorthandlink.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{shorthandlink.dbx}[2020/11/15 arbitrary links for shorthands]
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=uri]{shorthandlink}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{shorthandlink}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,
  maxnames=999, minalphanames=3, giveninits=true,
  datamodel=shorthandlink]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthandlink}
    {\bibhyperref{#1}}
    {\ifhyperref
       {\href{\thefield{shorthandlink}}{#1}}
       {#1}}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{tabmet,
  author        = {Ulrich Fischer and Max Heinzler and Roland Kilgus
                   and Friedrich Näher and Stefan Oesterle
                   and Heinz Paetzold and Werner Röhrer
                   and Andreas Stephan and Ralf Winkow},
  title         = {Tabellenbuch Metall},
  edition       = {42},
  year          = {2002},
  publisher     = {Verlag Europa-Lehrmittel},
  location      = {Haan-Gruiten},
  shorthand     = {Verlag 2002},
  shorthandlink = {https://example.com/verlag/2002},
}
@article{fakeart,
  author        = {Walter Schnell and Dietmar Gross and Werner Hauger},
  title         = {Technische Mechanik},
  volume        = {2},
  title         = {Elastostatik},
  edition       = {4},
  publisher     = {Springer},
  date          = {2002},
  location      = {Berlin},
  journal       = {Journal of BibTeX examples},
  shorthand     = {J Bib Examp 2002},
  shorthandlink = {https://doi.org/10.1257/jep.23.1.221},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Citing these\cite{tabmet,fakeart}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Linked shorthand citation.]

---

If you want to reuse the existing `doi` and `url` fields, you don't need the `.dbx` file, but the `bibhperref` field format needs to be slightly more complex.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,
  maxnames=999, minalphanames=3, giveninits=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}
    {\iffieldundef{url}
       {\bibhyperref{#1}}
       {\ifhyperref
          {\href{\thefield{url}}{#1}}
          {#1}}}
    {\ifhyperref
       {\href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}
       {#1}}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{tabmet,
  author        = {Ulrich Fischer and Max Heinzler and Roland Kilgus
                   and Friedrich Näher and Stefan Oesterle
                   and Heinz Paetzold and Werner Röhrer
                   and Andreas Stephan and Ralf Winkow},
  title         = {Tabellenbuch Metall},
  edition       = {42},
  year          = {2002},
  publisher     = {Verlag Europa-Lehrmittel},
  location      = {Haan-Gruiten},
  shorthand     = {Verlag 2002},
  url           = {https://example.com/verlag/2002},
}
@article{fakeart,
  author        = {Walter Schnell and Dietmar Gross and Werner Hauger},
  title         = {Technische Mechanik},
  volume        = {2},
  title         = {Elastostatik},
  edition       = {4},
  publisher     = {Springer},
  date          = {2002},
  location      = {Berlin},
  journal       = {Journal of BibTeX examples},
  shorthand     = {J Bib Examp 2002},
  doi           = {10.1257/jep.23.1.221},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Citing these\cite{tabmet,fakeart}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Extremely helpful. In your code I can also change `style` to  `style=numeric` or `style=authoryear`, and the links still go where I want, with no need for shorthands. (Arguably Bibliographies are vestigial when we can link straight to DOIs!),

Comment: It would be ideal to use the DOI or URL field if it exists for the hyperlink (as in my question first sentence), ie not to have to specify a custom link if not needed.