(short)journal-year citations rather than author-year, using natbib-style biblatex
I would sometimes like to be able to make my natbib citations look like Nature Comms (2023) rather than Smith et al (2023).
I'm willing to have the whole document work this way.
Multi-source citations lists, and disambiguation for multiple citations in the same year, etc, should work as normal.
Ideally, I would invoke this with style=shortjournalyear or style=journalyear in the usepackage command, but something hackier which modifies authoryear behavior might do.
There is apparently an already-defined field shortjournal in use in BibTeX, so this could be used, or a custom field (shorthandjournal?) could be used, which defaults to shortjournal's or journal's value if not defined in the database.
The example below is no longer very helpful for this (modified/split up) question. It attempts to use \DeclareCiteCommand definitions to get shortjournal-year citations, along with hyperlinking those citations to an external URL (e.g. doi).
Instead, I need a more "native" way for biber to do this itself, so that it can also properly assign a, b, c, etc suffixes for duplicate journal-year pairs, properly use the shorthands in Bibliographies, etc, and properly format single/multiple  \citet and \citep lists.
\documentclass{article}

  \begin{filecontents}{myreferences.bib}
@article{testone,
 author = {Alice Jones and Bob Smith},
 doi = {10.1016/foodlefish},
 journal = {Journal of Testing},
 shorthand-journal = {J Testing},
 shorthandlink = {https://doi.org/10.1016/foodlefish},
 title = {Test One},
 volume = {450},
 year = {2024}
}

@article{testtwo,
 author = {Alice Jones and Bob Smith},
 doi = {10.1016/foodlefish},
 journal = {Journal of Testing},
 shorthand-journal = {J Testing},
 shorthandlink = {https://doi.org/10.1016/foodlefish},
 title = {Test One},
 volume = {450},
 year = {2024}
}
  \end{filecontents}


\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=red, filecolor=magenta, urlcolor=cyan}

% Field mapping % It seems I have to have fieldtarget different from fieldsource to make it available to \printfield??
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=shorthand-journal, fieldtarget=shortjournal]
      \step[fieldsource=shorthandlink, fieldtarget=shortlink]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{shortjournal}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shortlink}{\url{#1}}

  

% Citation commands
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citejournal}
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
     {\iffieldundef{shortjournal}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
     \printfield{year}}
   {\iffieldundef{shortlink}
      {\printfield{shortjournal}}
      {\href{\thefield{shortlink}}{\printfield{shortjournal}}}%
     \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
     \printfield{year}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencitejournal}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\iffieldundef{shortjournal}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
     \printfield{year}}
    {\iffieldundef{shortlink}
      {\printfield{shortjournal}}
      {\href{\thefield{shortlink}}{\printfield{shortjournal}}}%
     \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
     \printfield{year}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\let\citep\parencitejournal
\let\citet\citejournal

% For debugging
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=red, filecolor=magenta, urlcolor=cyan}


\usepackage{color}




\begin{document}



\citet{testone}

\citep{testone}

\citet{testone,testtwo}

\citep{testone,testtwo}


\nocite{testone}
\fullcite{testone}

\printbibliography[title=Debug Bibliography]

\end{document}


To clarify: Do you ever want to have a different shorthandlink/shortlink than the DOI? If not, we can just do away with this and generate the link directly from the DOI.

Your main problem here is that the example uses field names that are not known to biblatex's data model. If you want to use a field that is not part of the standard data model as documented in the biblatex docs, you need to "register" the field with biblatex's data model. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163303/35864 for more info. A field called shortjournal exists, so the remapping makes that work. But shorthand-journal, shorthandlink and shortlink all do not exist in the standard data model and will be ignored.

Note also that you might get into trouble if you have several publications in the same journal from the same year. For author-year combinations Biber calculates so-called "extrdate" letters that are added to the year to make the labels unique. But Biber usually cannot calculate additional extradate info based on journal+year data. (Plus there'd be no good way to display this in the bibliography list at the end, as it would be assumed that any letters would refer to author+year data.)

Thanks @moewe. Yes, shortlink should be customizable in the DB. Aha! shortjournal existing explains a lot.
However maybe there are two separable problems. What I really want is a (natbib) clean way to cite shortjournal-year rather than author-year, but keeping other features like "extrdate".  I guess changing the hyperlink can be done separately. So: Is there a way to copy the author-year style into a shortjournal-year? I could reframe this whole question around that part.

Going at that task a different way a few years ago (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570855/biblatex-custom-citation-string-with-custom-hyperlink) is a bit of a cheat: it asks the bib file to specify the entire shorthand label. However, that doesn't work for \citet style citations.

Yes, please separate out the two questions, that makes it easier to focus on the relevant bits.

As to the journal-year citations: Do you also want to be able to use author-year citations in the same document? If so, it's pretty tricky to have the two systems alongside each other. But if you don't need author-year citations, it should be possible to configure biblatex to do journa-year citations with disambiguation and everything.

Thanks! Question modified. Okay, I'll grateful accept a solution that changes the citation style for the whole document

We can obtain a journal-year citation style by using an author-year style and modifying \DeclareLabelname to also respect the journals for label name creation. Unfortunately, \DeclareLabelname only accepts name fields, so we need to remap journal and friends to internal name fields. Name fields are special, though, so we need to wrap the journal name into additional curly braces during the mapping step.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=red, filecolor=magenta, urlcolor=cyan}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=shortjournal,  fieldtarget=namea, final]
      \step[fieldsource=namea, match=\regexp{(.*)}, replace={\{$1\}}]
    }
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=journal,  fieldtarget=journaltitle]
      \step[fieldsource=journaltitle,  fieldtarget=nameb, final]
      \step[fieldsource=nameb, match=\regexp{(.*)}, replace={\{$1\}}]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareLabelname{%
  \field{namea}
  \field{nameb}
  \field{shortauthor}
  \field{author}
  \field{shorteditor}
  \field{editor}
  \field{translator}
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{testone,
  author       = {Alice Jones and Bob Smith},
  doi          = {10.1016/foodlefish},
  journal      = {Journal of Testing},
  shortjournal = {J Testing},
  title        = {Test One},
  volume       = {450},
  year         = {2024},
}
@article{testtwo,
  author       = {Alice Jones and Bob Smith},
  doi          = {10.1016/foodlefish},
  journal      = {Journal of Testing},
  shortjournal = {J Testing},
  title        = {Test One},
  volume       = {450},
  year         = {2024},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{testone}

\parencite{testtwo}

\printbibliography[title=Debug Bibliography]
\end{document}


Note that I used the standard fields journal (journaltitle) and shortjournal here and not the non-standard shorthand-journal field.
